# How do I reference modules .egg files supplied via the --py-files option of spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using `spark-submit` with the `py-files` option to include an egg (`spark_submit_test_lib-0.1-py2.7.egg`) that I've built.
Structure of that .egg is basically:

```
root
|- EGG-INFO
|- spark_submit_test_lib
     |- __init__.pyc
     |- __init__.py
     |- spark_submit_test_lib.pyc
     |- spark_submit_test_lib.py
         |- def do_sum()
```

in my driver script `spark_submit_test.py` I have this import:

```
from spark_submit_test_lib import do_sum
```

I submit to my hadoop cluster using:

```
spark-submit --queue 'myqueue' --py-files spark_submit_test_lib-0.1-py2.7.egg --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn spark_submit_test.py
```

it fails with error:

```
ImportError: No module named spark_submit_test_lib
```

I tried changing the import statement to

```
from spark_submit_test_lib.spark_submit_test_lib import do_sum
```

but to no avail, still getting the same error.

I see someone has had a similar problem (in that case he/she wants spark-submit to use a file inside the .egg as the driver - so a similar problem but not the same): [What filepath or dot notation should I use when using spark-submit.py with .egg files as an argument to --py-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387803/what-filepath-or-dot-notation-should-i-use-when-using-spark-submit-py-with-egg) but at the time of writing there are no answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

this command works for me

```
spark2-submit --master yarn \
            --driver-memory 20g \
            --num-executors 50 \
            --executor-cores 1 \
            --deploy-mode client \
            --jars spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar \
            --py-files spark_submit_test_lib-0.1-py2.7.egg \
            driver.py
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is due to the fact that the --py-files argument is meant to supply files that will be used by nodes on the spark cluster, not in your driver program. I believe your driver python program needs to be local. I could be wrong about this but this is what I have experienced and my eventual conclusion to the question you linked.

Comment: OK great, thx for coming over here and answering. I actually managed to get it working and did so using `from spark_submit_test_lib.spark_submit_test_lib import do_sum` as I wrote above. I must have been doing something else incorrect when I attempted it prior to posting this thread - no idea what. Anyway, glad to say that I now have it working.